# communication between server and android app

Tags: android, database, laravel, server, response

i try to send information from android app to server to save in data base my code runs correctly but no data saved in database and i didn't get any response. i don't know where is the mistake in my code

```
   private class postData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

      // private final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "",
     //       "Saving data to server. Please wait...", true);

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // perform long running operation operation

        // SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILE, 0);
        //String server = settings.getString("server", "");
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://phone.com/request_job");
        String json = "";
        String responseStr="";

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ticket", "welcome"));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            try {
                httpclient.execute(httppost);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            // ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler=new BasicResponseHandler();
            //String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

            //  if (Boolean.parseBoolean(responseBody)) {
            //  dialog.cancel();
            // }
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());




        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.i("HTTP Failed", e.toString());
        }
        return responseStr;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String responseStr) {
        super.onPostExecute(responseStr);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),responseStr,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if(responseStr.equals("true")){
            // Update your Button here
           Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"donefinally",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
```

my code in server

```
          public function check_user(Request $request){
    $ticket = new ticket;// this line responsible to set data in database
    $ticket->ticket = $request->ticket;

        return response()->json(['data','true']);
}


}
```

Comment: I think you forgot to save the data you received. @Shorouk

Comment: `responseStr = "IOException: " + e.getMessage();`. Add that to the catch block of your IOException.

Comment: i saved it but still no data shows and i can't get true response

Comment: Then there is sure error in php code, put full code if possible. @ShoroukAdel

Answer (score 0):

In your server, do

```
$ticket = new ticket;// this line responsible to set data in database
$ticket->ticket = $request->ticket;
$ticket->save(); //<-- this line will save
```

Or in one go

```
$ticket = Ticket::create([
    'ticket' => $request->ticket
]);
...
```

Now, make sure you call your `ticket` class properly. Not sure whether it's capital T (Ticket) or lowercase (ticket).

**Edit**

Since it's not working, you need to debug it step by step to see where the bottleneck is. First, in your function, simply do

```
return response()->json($request->ticket); 
//This will prove that the request makes it to the server
```

Once you are sure you request makes it to the server, try to manually save something like

```
Ticket::create([
    'ticket' => 'random string'
]);
```

You can call this function directly from your browser to test if it works. If nothing is saved in the db, make sure you have a `$fillable` array in your model and that you can connect properly to the db.

Comment: i did that and save ticket but still no data send to database also i cannot get true response @EddytheDove